# How to compute the image of $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 $?

Tags: functions, integers

I'm asked to compute the image of the function $f:\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$,defined by, $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 $ ?

At first I tried to compute the limit when $(x,y) \rightarrow (\infty,\infty)$ , but I couldn't do it,I don't even know if It's corect aproach.

Then I saw that:

- $8k = (2k+1)^2 - (2k-1)^2$ , i.e when x and y are odd
- $16k = (2k+2)^2 - (2k-2)^2$ , i.e when x and y are even

but still there is no restriction saying that x and y should be both odd or even,so It doesn't help me much. Anyone can help me with some ideas ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

If you can hit $n$ you can also hit $-n$ by switching $x$ and $y$, so I'll just focus on positive numbers.

You can hit all odd numbers: $(k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k+1$.

You can hit all multiples of 4: for 4 times an odd number take the solution above and multiply $x$ and $y$ by 2; for 4 times an even number you've given solutions.

So we're only left with considering numbers that are congruent to $2$ $(mod$ $4)$. Consider squares mod 4, and see if you can work out what is happening.

Comment: okay , I'll try